# JavaScript - How can a function return multiple times despite being called once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is just some random code that I made up, but what I don't understand it. The method will be called once when you click on the button, but why does `"test"`  keep being printed into the console like the method is being called over and over again, all because on the `on.("keyup",...` I mean after a value is returned, the method shouldn't be referenced anymore in memory. Even alongside that, I'm not even using a promise. Should we enter the method and immediately exit anyway?

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/71mfw5qa/9/)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work

Comment: Updated with a fiddle link

Comment: Nothing in that fiddle calls your `runit()` function, but your assumption that "after a value is returned, the method shouldn't be referenced anymore in memory" is incorrect: once an event handler is in place, it stays in place until you remove it (or the DOM element it's attached to.)  (Also, calling `runit()` multiple times would register multiple handlers, each of which would fire on the same keyup event.)

Comment: Code has to go in the question. Your questions cannot depend on links to 3rd party code-hosting sites like JSFiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run “`runit`” function, you **REGISTER** the inner anonymous function to run whenever a key has been released (keyup event).

`Runit` never prints anything to the console.

The inner anonymous function is executed every time you release a key on the keyboard